# Tkinter button creation

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I have a list of strings that I do not know the length of. They list could be between 5 and 20 strings...

How can I create a single button for each string in that list, the buttons will go across the screen UNTIL the end of the screen, then enter to the next line and continue across again.

```
def fileButtons():
    for i, k in enumerate(initialfiles):
        initButtons = Button(master, text=k).grid(column = i, row = 1)
```

This code will just make the buttons go all the way across and never return to a new line. Even if I create a frame and put the buttons into the frame it does not enter to the next line. I am assuming it is because I am defining the row to be 1.

Comment: Great job on editing your answer as to not look AS petty, but down-voting my question accomplished that for you. I was simply stating that I knew the problem but did not know how to fix it.

Comment: you have no idea whether I downvoted or not. I will say that I think this question deserves a downvote though -- it shows absolutely no attempt at any research, or any attempt at trying to solve the problem yourself. You even knew what the problem was, but didn't take the logical step of trying to use separate row numbers to see what would happen. You are smart enough to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your constructive criticism. You are correct. I will show my research and format my questions better from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You're right it's because your entering each row to be 1. So, the widgets will all be inside the grid with differing columns but all on the same row.

You need to make some kind of breakpoint to put widgets on new rows.

Here's a random example which you can adjust to fit your needs.

```
def fileButtons():
    row = 1
    for i, k in enumerate(initialfiles):
        if i % 2: row += 1
        initButtons = Button(master, text=k).grid(column = i, row = row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show an exact answer for what I was personally looking for:

```
def buttonUI(self):
    row = 0
    column = 0
    for i, k in enumerate(initialfiles):
        if i >= 4:
            row += 1
        column += 1
        if column == 4:
            column = 0
        b = Button(self,text=k).grid(column = column, row = row, sticky=W+E)

    self.pack()
```

With the addition of what Slayer has answered, I also defined column. Finally to make it a little nicer looking I added the sticky option because the length of 'k' varies for each button.Thanks for the input.